# How to query values from json array object in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

One of my column response store the value like this in postgres table database:

```json
{"result": [{"cin": "134234", "entityName": "xyz"}, {"cin": "2452352", "entityName": "uvw"}]
```

I want to return cin value.
I tried

```
SELECT response->'result'->'cin' AS Cin  
FROM test where id = 1 ;
```

but it returned null;

Can anyone provide me a simple solution.

Comment: What exactly is the result you want? An array with `[1, 2]`?

Comment: i just want the value of cin  i.e 1 and  i am using postgres 13

Comment: There are **two** cin values in your json - which one do you want?

Comment: cin with value '1'

Comment: so you want to test if there is such an array element? Or do you want the value of `entityName` (for `cin = 1`) as the result?

Comment: I want the value of cin using entity name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JSON path query for this:

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(response, '$.result[*] ? (@.entityName == "xyz").cin')
from test
where id = 1;
```

This assumes that `response` is a `jsonb` column (which it should be). If it's not you need to cast it `response::jsonb`

The result is a JSONB value again